# Passing a style prop to react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

I have a typescript Next.js app that's misbehaving (or I'm just stupid). 
There's a component `<CluckHUD props="styles.Moon" />` that is supposed to pass the theme as a css classname. This is supposed to customize the theme on a per-page basis.

Component here

```
export default function CluckHUD({ theme }: { theme: any }) {
    return (
        <nav className={{...theme}}>
            <ul className={styles.navbarNav}>
```

(Yes they all have closing tags, and yes I imported the component in the first file)

Except when everything runs, the class is `[object Object]`. Am I missing something, or is the whole approach wrong?

Comment: You're spreading out an object into the className! What do you expect? The classname goes within the first `{curly braces}` when passing in the prop. What you're doing is creating an object within those braces and spreading out whatever the heck `theme` is. Even if `theme` is a string, you're still passing an object. Just do `className={theme}` and set the type of `theme` to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to solve your problem. 
Please use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) node module in your project.